# Ambiguous `id` Field

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have the following two tables:

```
system
- id
- systemName
- idOrganization

organization
- id
- officeSymbol
```

I am running the following query and receiving an `id` is ambiguous error:

```
SELECT system.systemName, organization.officeSymbol
FROM system
LEFT JOIN (organization)
ON (system.idOrganization = organization.id)
```

As you can see, I'm not selecting the `id` column. If I place `system.id` within the list of fields to select, I no longer receive this error. Unfortunately, the manner in which this data is handled I can't return the `id` - we don't want it displayed to the user.

Also, if I add `GROUP BY system.systemName` I no longer get the error - but this just doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

Note: The `LEFT JOIN` is intentional as not all systems will be assigned to an Organization.

```
SELECT VERSION()
--> 5.0.77-community-log

CREATE TABLE system (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `systemName` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idOrganization` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_system_organization` (`idOrganization`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_system_organization` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`idOrganization`) 
    REFERENCES `organization` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE organization (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `officeSymbol` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested on `5.0.77`:

```
SELECT  VERSION();

VERSION()
5.0.77


CREATE TABLE organization (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `officeSymbol` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE system (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `systemName` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idOrganization` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_system_organization` (`idOrganization`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_system_organization`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idOrganization`)
    REFERENCES `organization` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT
INTO   organization
VALUES
        (1, 'Organization 1'),
        (2, 'Organization 2');
INSERT
INTO     system
VALUES  (1, 'System 1', 1),
        (2, 'System 2', 2);
SELECT  system.systemName, organization.officeSymbol
FROM    system
LEFT JOIN
        (organization)
ON      (system.idOrganization = organization.id);

systemName      officeSymbol
System 1        Organization 1
System 2        Organization 2
```

Everything works fine.

Note that `LEFT JOIN` is useless here, since you have a `FOREIGN KEY` to `organization`, and there will always be an `organization` for every given `system`.

In your comment to `@Artem Barger`'s post you said:

> I'm only selecting on 5 of the 42 fields shared between these 2 tables

Is it that there are other fields in the tables and/or query?

Since you have a syntactic error, every comma may matter.

Comment: Posted the creation scripts as requested as well as version information. The query is just being run directly in query browser at the moment, returning Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous, ErrorNo: 1052.

Comment: Other fields within the tables. My concern is, using DISTINCT would only return unique rows given this query, but there may be other data that leads these two records to render two result rows (but I don't want that data returned to the end user).

Syntax errors are just due to typing - this code resides on an independent network, but I am confident it is valid over there.

Comment: @Michael: if you want your issue to be solved, you'll need to paste the EXACT table creation scripts and the EXACT query you run. The way you pasted your tables and your query, everything works fine, nobody will able to figure out the problem from the stripped code.

Comment: Marked as the winning answer simply because it was the most helpful and everything you tried worked. Unfortunately, I simply can't show everything to get an exact response. I ended up using GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT() to take care of fields that may be replicated with different data (rare, if ever, but still logical in regards to the data model).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what is happening, since I'm not familiar enough with mySql, but I always prefer to name columns like SystemID and OrganizationID and not gernically like "ID".

Naming your columns this way, would result in PK-FK combinations that have the same name:

```
bad PK-FK names       good PK-FK names
system                system
  id                    SystemID
  systemName            systemName
  idOrganization        OrganizationID  <--

organization          organization
  id                    OrganizationID  <--
  officeSymbol          officeSymbol
```

Comment: Couldn't disagree more. Organization.OrganizationID is redundant, and doesn't denote any difference between your primary key and your foreign keys.

Comment: @Todd Gardner, I would never have "Organization.OrganizationID" in a query, just "o.OrganizationID". But I'd never have a "idOrganization" as a FK to "id", try to support that in a few years with a few hundred or several thousand tables later!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your query would be generating that: normally you get that error message when you do:

```
SELECT id /* This should have been qualified with system. or organization. */
FROM system
LEFT JOIN (organization)
ON (system.idOrganization = organization.id)
```

Are you sure that query is exactly giving you that error? If you trimmed it down for SO, you might have cut out the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know mysql, only sqlserver, however, when using field names like "id" and table names like "system" i'd be sure to square bracket all of the table and columns names like so. Might be worth a shot?

```
SELECT
    [system].[systemName],
    [organization].[officeSymbol]
FROM
    [system]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [organization]
ON
    [system].[idOrganization] = [organization].[id]
```

Comment: Mysql uses backtick (`something`), not [something]

Comment: Thanks, as I said, don't know mysql, was just an idea as the sql itself looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Michael, would placing the id in single quotes (`) (or square brackets like in SQL Server, or whatever works for mysql) help fixing the issue?

```
...
ON (system.`idOrganization` = organization.`id`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT system.systemName, organization.officeSymbol
FROM system, organization
WHERE system.idOrganization = organization.id
```

This should join the tables together properly, even if not all systems are assigned to an organization.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that will do an INNER JOIN, not a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score -1):

It seems very bizarre to me that you'd be getting that error (though my main experience isn't with mysql). I'd try with aliasing your tables.

```
SELECT s.systemName, o.officeSymbol
FROM system as s
LEFT JOIN (organization as o)
ON (s.idOrganization = o.id)
```